# Ftp - unable to connect when uploading

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, ftp

I want to upload multiple files on the server using ftp. The problem that I am facing right now, when I upload a files, it fails to connect with ftp. This happen often and I realize if the file is `> 1 MB`, it will fail to connect.

The server is using Windows Server 2012 and XAMPP for the apache server. On the `php.ini` file, I change the `upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and max_execution_time` to a bigger value and use `pasive mode` but the problem remains.

If the file size is small, there will be no issue to upload. Do I have to make adjustment to the server or is this regarding the network issue? I have not much experience in dealing with ftp and server.

Comment: It does not make sense. At the time of connection, file size cannot matter. What error are you getting exactly? Do you have some code? If you have, why didn't you posted on [so]?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am getting `Couldn't connect to ftp server` using the `ftp_connect` function on php.

Comment: Please move your question to [so]. Show us your code. And start by isolating the problem from HTTP upload. Use just a simple upload of a file already located at the machine/server that runs the PHP code.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help. Will edit and transfer the question to stack overflow